# How to make JS media query work properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Media query in JS works, but as soon as it's nested within a function such as onscroll or onclick, they'll not work properly.

**I'll just put the code in here just in case you want to resize window easier:**
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GP7P1ENXH9JY

Try to test the media query if it works, I know it works, **but** as soon as you resize it to 768px(desktop) and started scrolling down, it starts to revert back to the tablet media query(600px) and the color changes too, even though the window size is still 768px width. How do I fix this?

```js
window.onscroll = function() {stickynavbar();}

var element1 = document.getElementById("element1");
var element2 = document.getElementById("element2");
var myBtn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

var desktop = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
var tablet = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)");

function stickynavbar() {

  function element1Query(desktop){
      if (desktop.matches){
          element1.style.background = "darkred";
      }
      else{
          element1.style.background = "black";
      }
  }
  element1Query(desktop);
  desktop.addListener(element1Query);

  function element1TQuery(tablet){
      if (tablet.matches){
          element1.style.background = "darkblue";
      }
      else{
          element1.style.background = "black";
      }
  }
  element1TQuery(tablet);
  tablet.addListener(element1TQuery);

  function element2Query(desktop){
      if (desktop.matches){
          element2.style.background = "darkgreen";
      }
      else{
          element2.style.background = "gray";
      }
  }
  element2Query(desktop);
  desktop.addListener(element2Query);

  function element2TQuery(tablet){
      if (tablet.matches){
          element2.style.background = "yellow";
      }
      else{
          element2.style.background = "gray";
      }
  }

  element2TQuery(tablet);
  tablet.addListener(element2TQuery);
}
```

```css
.element1{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 1000px;
        background: black;
    }
    .element2{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 1000px;
        background: gray;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="element1" id="element1"></div>
<div class="element2" id="element2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your tablet query also match `768px width`

Comment: Yes, I tried to use (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 767px), but got even worse, the desktop's query won't work that way

Comment: well it do works for me, can you provide a link that doesn't work?

Comment: I provided the link above, it does work when you resize it. Try to resize it to 768px desktop query, and try to scroll down, it'll immediately revert back to tablet query and that's the problem

Comment: @ VladdCantor ? it definitely doesn't have `max-width` in it?

Comment: As I said I tried it but it got even worse and if you do it that way, desktop query will not work.

Comment: @ VladdCantor  So you don't want to provide a non-working link, then I can not keep help you. (If you do test it, why not share the link actually?)

Comment: Ow okay here you go bro https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GP7PZMXH6FQE

Comment: OK it doesn't work anymore. Thanks for provide the link.

Comment: The problem probably is `element1Query` and `element1TQuery` have race condition here.

Comment: here is a fixed link https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GP7QDKYQ6H30

Comment: ? isn't I provide a fixed link [just before your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66929695/how-to-make-js-media-query-work-properly?noredirect=1#comment118308449_66929695)?

Comment: also I post an answer below :)

Comment: Yeah bro I appreciate it so much. Been looking for answers but no one helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to achieve it, the function only handles when the state matches, thus prevent the race condition

```js
let element1 = document.getElementById("element1")
let desktop = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)")
let tablet = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px) and (max-width:767px)")
let small = window.matchMedia("(max-width:599px)")

desktop.addEventListener('change', function(){
  if(desktop.matches)
    element1.style.background = "darkred";
})

tablet.addEventListener('change', function(){
  if(tablet.matches)
    element1.style.background = "darkblue";
})

small.addEventListener('change', function(){
  if(small.matches)
    element1.style.background = "black";
})
```

```css
.element1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: black;
}

.element2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="element1" id="element1"></div>
  <div class="element2" id="element2"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is element1Query and element1TQuery have race condition here.

```js
let element1 = document.getElementById("element1");
let desktop = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
let tablet = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px) and (max-width:767px)");

function element1Query() {
  if (desktop.matches) {
    element1.style.background = "darkred";
  } else if (tablet.matches) {
    element1.style.background = "darkblue";
  } else {
    element1.style.background = "black";
  }
}
desktop.addEventListener('change', element1Query);
tablet.addEventListener('change', element1Query);
```

```css
.element1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: black;
}

.element2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="element1" id="element1"></div>
  <div class="element2" id="element2"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro I appreciate it! I've been looking for answers but no one helps. :D